# Nuxt.js page reloading on for submission even with stop.prevent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I've been reading some questions about this exact same topic like but none of them seems to be working for me and I can't spot the error.

I have this form:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form @submit.stop.prevent="submit">
      <input v-model="name" type="text" />
      <input v-model="email" type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the following script

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      const res = await this.$axios.request({
        url: 'locahost:3000/404', // This route doesn't exists
        method: 'post',
        data: this.$data
      })

      console.log(res.status)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, there are more than one input in the form and I'm using `stop.prevent` when binding the submit event in the form.

I want to treat any possible errors in the axios request in the script part and update the page based on that (showing an error div or whatever) but without reloading it. However, the page reloads and is going to a 404 error page.

I'm using Nuxt 2.12.2 and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer just by trial and error and it was easier than I thought... It was only about unhandled promise rejection. As I'm using `async/await` I need to treat exceptions correctly and I was not doing that, the rejection was being propagated and the error handled by nuxt. So changing my code to:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      try {
        const res = await this.$axios.request({
          url: 'locahost:3000/404', // This route doesn't exists
          method: 'post',
          data: this.$data
        })

        console.log(res.status)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

That will prevent the error to be handled elsewhere and resulting in a redirection to a 404 page or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the form behaviour by only using the data in your submit method and trigger it by @click on the button without any submit type, like this :

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <input v-model="name" type="text" />
      <input v-model="email" type="text" />
      <button @click="() => submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Like this you will avoid any kind of side effect from the form as you don't need any form data in your axios request...

Comment: Actually I do need to send the form data in my axios request. Anyway, thanks for your help. The error was elsewhere, it was because of unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: Yes no problem, I meant 'form-data' not the data you get from the form that you will exploit as json in your request anyway...but glad to see you solve your problem !

Comment: Oh! Sorry Hugo, I misunderstood you! Thanks again